# Division of sum of time

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the average hours per event out of this query:

```
 SEC_TO_TIME(sum(q2.HOURS))/sum(q2.Events)as Average
```

TIME_TO_SEC(sum(q2.HOURS)) result = 838:59:59 
I want to divide this by the number of events = 160

But the query doesn't give me the expected result.

Hope someone can help me. 
Thanks

Comment: And what result does it produce?

Comment: Maybe you could show us the full query?

Comment: And how can you divide `838:59:59` by a number: the former is not a number

Comment: Would it be possible to divide just the hours by 160 in this case.

Comment: Or what I actually want to do is to convert the hours into a number, so 10:30:00 gets 10,5 or 10:25:00 gets to 10,15 and then divide by the number of events. As per my calculation I have 1051,61 hours divided by 160 would be 6,57

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution -

```
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(q2.HOURS) * 3600 / SUM(q2.Events)) AS Average
```

It will count average in seconds and output result as TIME data type.

Comment: You probably meant `* 3600` if `q2.HOURS` holds number of hours

Comment: Oh yes, I meant that. Thanks;)

Comment: Unfortunately this is giving me exactly the same result as (sum(q2.Hours)

Comment: Can you add CREATE TABLE and some INSERT statements to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well it's hard to tell without knowing exact datatype of `q2.HOURS` column and sample data, but if it is a time data type (and your comments suggest that it is the case) then do it that way

```
SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(q2.hours)) / 3600 / SUM(q2.events) average
  FROM 
(
  SELECT '10:30:00' hours, 3 events
   UNION ALL
  SELECT '04:30:00', 2
) q2
```

Output: *15 hours (10:30:00 + 04:30:00) =  / 5 events = 3 hours per event*

```
| AVERAGE |
-----------
|       3 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/12986)**

Comment: @SandraGrassl Do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score -2):

Try putting the whole division inside the parentheses in `SEC_TO_TIME`,assuming q2.Hours stores an integer value:

```
SEC_TO_TIME(sum(q2.HOURS)/sum(q2.Events)) as Average
```

If q2.Hours stores a time value, you must first convert the time to an integer using `TIME_TO_SEC` and then divide by the sum of events, and only after that convert it back to a time format:

```
SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(sum(q2.HOURS))/sum(q2.Events)) as Average
```

Comment: Unfortunately the results are the same. Let me ask differently. Is it possible to convert the Hours into a number so 10:15:00 gets 10,15 for example.